# dynamic building of a list

Tags: javascript, html

I was wonder how I could get input from a user, then display that input underneath on a new line along with any previous input.

I was wondering if this could be done in either HTML or Javascript

Comment: You could specify the language/technology you are using?

Comment: What environment are you talking about?

Comment: good point :) HTML or JavaScript

Answer (score 6):

At its most trivial:

```
<form>
  <input name="text" type="text"/>
  <input type="button" value=":)" onClick="document.getElementById('output').innerHTML+=form.text.value+'<br/>'"/>
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Technically you don't even need a form: you can just use a naked <input> tag combined with a <button> tag.

Comment: Hi Matt
You are a genius.  
This is exactly what I was looking for. 
Thanks

Comment: I am even going to leave in the :)